# writing node.js api callback or not

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-dynamodb, restify

Folks,
  Assume an API written in NodeJS (restify.js) that utilizes a NOSQL backend (mongo or dynamo).

When you have a blocking operation, such as reading or writing to a file, its always a great idea to write things in non-blocking fashion... however...  when your operations take milliseconds to complete, should you use callbacks???

Imagine api calls such as https://api.foo.com/v1/bar/baz, gets routed to a function that gets a quick response from NoSQL engine, formats the response in JSON, and puts it back on the browser.

In this scenario, should you use call backs?  Writing this to scale out to hundreds of concurrent requests.

Thanks!

Comment: Blocking operations in node.js? That must be new.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what do you mean?

Comment: How would you not use callbacks if the engine being called is using aysnc patterns? It's either that or an event. You can't make something that functions asynchronously be synchronous.

Answer (score 3):

Even if your operation takes milliseconds to complete, and you will use sync implementation (for example - readFileSync vs readFile - which is async) - all other concurrent requests you mentioned will have to wait for sync operation to complete.

In other words, if you have a choice, you shall always use non-blocking implementation if your goal is to write scalable solution.

Suitable scenario for purely sync operation would be loading configuration when application starts, and after that you shall avoid any long operations which could block the event loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'd phrase the answer in the form of some facts:

1. Use the CPU, an idle CPU is wasting money and wasting your user's time
2. Queue up operations to complete as quickly as possible, in Node this is done by using async operations within a function (`setImmediate`/`Timeout`/`Interval` just put new work on the queue and aren't async)
3. While each operation from the queue is run synchronously and only one runs at a time, as soon as that operation starts an async operation and completes it's processing, another queued operation may begin
4. Async work may happen on another thread (implementation/platform dependent), or it may happen within another process or another machine.
5. While another CPU/thread/machine does work, the NodeJS process can continue to keep busy processing the queue
6. When an operation completes, the queue can be rechecked for more work, or handle a response from another CPU/thread/machine.

As the async pattern is so common in either the form of an event or a callback function, it's easy to learn (and follow). It keeps the processor busy when it might not have been busy. By keeping the NodeJS process busy, more work is being done.

In the case you mention, using a NoSQL engine, assuming it supports async (like MongoDB does for example), use the async operations, especially when end-users may be waiting. Many native drivers for NoSQL databases offer only async support in the form of callbacks/events.